# Разбить элементы списка посимвольно

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно разбить уловный список `['1', '22', '333']` по символам, т.е. чтобы получился список `['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']`

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

На функциональщине в одну строчку:

```
reduce(lambda a, x: a + x, map(lambda x: list(x), ['1', '22', '333']))
```

Поясняю - `reduce` принимает на вход функцию, которая объединяет результаты разбиения списка функцией `map`. `Map` принимает на вход функцию и начальный массив, над каждым элементом массива выполняется данная функция. То же самое можно выразить следующим кодом:

```
>>> result_list = []
>>> for x in ['1', '22', '333']:
...     for y in list(x):
...         result_list.append(y)
... 
>>> print(result_list)
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']
```

---

Сравнение по скорости предложенных вариантов:

Вариант с использованием `join` и объединением в строку результата уделал всех. Оно и неудивительно — все операции здесь быстрые. Будет работать с любыми `iterable` объектами:

```
$python3 -m timeit "list(''.join(['1', '22', '333']))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.318 usec per loop
```

[Вариант с использованием генератора списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556004/176345) из ответа @jfs действительно работает быстро:

```
$python3 -m timeit "[char for s in ['1', '22', '333'] for char in s]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.452 usec per loop
```

Вариант с использованием `sum` занимает третье место по скорости, однако по моему мнению, проигрывает в интуитивности:

```
$python3 -m timeit "sum([list(i) for i in ['1', '22', '333']], [])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.984 usec per loop
```

Вариант на `map-reduce` является самым медленным. Почему я его использую? Потому что мне нравятся цепочки вызовов. Остальное — вкусовщина. Однако даже Гвидо ненавидит `reduce` (и вынес его в `functools` в *python3*)

```
$python3 -m timeit "from functools import reduce; reduce(lambda a, x: a + x, map(lambda x: list(x), ['1', '22', '333']))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.16 usec per loop
```

Вариант с `collections` покрывает все случаи, когда передаваемый объект может быть неитерируемым (число, например), однако цена за такое — большое время выполнения:

```
$python3 -m timeit "import collections

def it(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
        for ob in obj:
            if isinstance(ob, collections.Iterable) and len(ob) > 1:
                yield from it(ob)
            else: yield ob
    else:
        yield obj

list(it(['1', 2, [2, 44, '123', ('qwe')], 2]))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 usec per loop
```

Comment: Вариант с `reduce()` является нечитаемым и неэффективным кодом. Вложенный цикл можно с [генератором списков использовать, что может быть более читаемо и эффективно по сравнению с `reduce()` примером](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556004/23044)

Comment: @jfs дополнил ответ

Comment: Сравнение скоростей на таких данных выглядит странно. В таком случае самым быстрым способом будет создать список `['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']`.

Comment: а у меня summ последний :)

Answer (score 12):

Раз уж тут начали коллекционировать разные способы, предложу такое:

```
list(''.join(['1', '22', '333']))
```

(Теперь кто-то должен сравнить производительность всех вариантов :)

Comment: Теперь есть сравнение :)

Comment: `chars = ''.join(strings)` отличный вариант, если автору нужна просто (неизменяемая) последовательность символов: можно не вызывать `list()`.

Answer (score 10):

А можно сделать так:

```
l = ['1', '22', '333']
s = sum([list(i) for i in l], [])
print(s)
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']
```

Comment: Это квадратичный алгоритм : при добавлении каждого списка, суммарный список заново создаётся (как маляр из анекдота: [*"Ничего не могу поделать—Каждый день я ухожу все дальше и дальше от банки!"*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) (для сравнения `''.join(strings)` и [генератор списков из моего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556004/23044) линейны по кол-ву символов).

Answer (score 10):

Чтобы получить список символов из списка строк, можно использовать вложенный цикл в генераторе списков:

```
strings = ['1', '22', '333']
chars = [char for s in strings for char in s]
# chars -> ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']
```

Похожий вопрос: [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279).

Согласно [@Alex Martelli этот вариант может быть быстрее решений, использующих `sum()`, `reduce()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/4279). Решение с генератором списков также более читаемо по сравнению с `reduce()`.

Answer (score 6):

```
import collections

def it(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
        for ob in obj:
            if isinstance(ob, collections.Iterable) and len(ob) > 1:
                yield from it(ob)
            else: yield ob
    else:
        yield obj

a = list(it(['1', 2, [2, 44, '123', ('qwe')], 2]))
print(a)
['1', 2, 2, 44, '1', '2', '3', 'q', 'w', 'e', 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Держи:

```
a = ['1', '22', '333']
a = [x for x in ''.join(a)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
from functools import wraps, reduce

def tefn(fn, args, kwargs):
    t = time.time()
    tuple(fn(*args, **kwargs))
    return t - time.time()

def efn(fn, args, kwargs):
    t = time.time()
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return t - time.time()

def runTime(tp=0, count=25):
    def dec(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print(fn)
            res = tefn if tp else efn
            return sum(res(fn, args, kwargs) for _ in range(count)) / count
        return wrap
    return dec


@runTime()
def fnTuple(): return tuple(char for s in list_ for char in s)
@runTime(tp=1)
def fnIter(): return iter(char for s in list_ for char in s)
@runTime()
def fnList(): return list(char for s in list_ for char in s)
@runTime(tp=1)
def fnYield():
    for a in list_: yield from a
@runTime(tp=1)
def fnJoin(): return ''.join(list_)
@runTime()
def fnSumm(): return sum([list(i) for i in list_], [])
@runTime()
def fnReduce(): return reduce(lambda a, x: a + x, map(lambda x: list(x), list_))
@runTime()
def fnNew(): return ['1' * 999, '22' * 999, '333' * 999] * 99

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_ = ['1' * 999, '22' * 999, '333' * 999] * 99
    g = globals()
    result = list((fn.__name__, fn()) for fn in (g[f] for f in g if f.startswith('fn')))
    result.sort(key=lambda r: r[1], reverse=True)
    for e, r in enumerate(result):
        print(e, r)
```

OUT:

```
<function fnReduce at 0x02938FA8>
<function fnNew at 0x0293B078>
<function fnList at 0x02938D68>
<function fnTuple at 0x028F7348>
<function fnYield at 0x02938DF8>
<function fnIter at 0x02938CD8>
<function fnJoin at 0x02938E88>
<function fnSumm at 0x02938F18>
0 ('fnNew', 0.0)
1 ('fnJoin', -0.018803834915161133)
2 ('fnYield', -0.04936907768249512)
3 ('fnTuple', -0.061401805877685546)
4 ('fnList', -0.06224835395812988)
5 ('fnIter', -0.07298644065856934)
6 ('fnSumm', -0.8121062469482422)
7 ('fnReduce', -0.8314747619628906)
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['1', 2, [2, 44, '123', ('qwe')], 2]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
a = list(''.join(map(str, df.explode('a')['a'])))
```